# How to extract 2D data from a multidimensional Convex hull?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, convex-hull

I have a multidimensional array and I create a Convex hull out of it, and I would like to extract 2D bounding hulls of the main multi-dimensional hull. But I don't know how to do it, without actually creating a convex hull first. 
My test code creates a 3d hull and then I use a function to extract 2D data out of it.

```
def get_convex_hull_3D(x_param, n_samples):
    np.random.seed(2394)
    x = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size=(n_samples, 3)) 

    # Scaling Points to lower and upper bound
    x[:,0] = np.minimum(x_param[0], x_param[1]) + x[:,0]* np.abs(x_param[1]-x_param[0])
    x[:,1] = np.minimum(x_param[2], x_param[3]) + x[:,1]* np.abs(x_param[3]-x_param[2])
    x[:,2] = np.minimum(x_param[4], x_param[5]) + x[:,2]* np.abs(x_param[5]-x_param[4])

    f = np.zeros((n_samples,3))  

    for i in range (n_samples):
        f[i,0] = test_function(x[i,0], x[i,1], x[i,2])[0]
        f[i,1] = test_function(x[i,0], x[i,1], x[i,2])[1]
        f[i,2] = test_function(x[i,0], x[i,1], x[i,2])[2]

    hull = ConvexHull(f)
    hull_center = get_center_point(f)

    return hull, hull_center, f, x

def get_bounding_hull_3D(hull, func_val):
    bounding_hull_3D = [[],[],[]]  
    for vertex in hull.vertices:
        bounding_hull_3D[0].append(func_val[vertex,0])
        bounding_hull_3D[1].append(func_val[vertex,1])
        bounding_hull_3D[2].append(func_val[vertex,2])
    return bounding_hull_3D

def get_bounding_hull_2D(hull, func_val):
    bounding_hull_2D = [[],[]]  
    for vertex in hull.vertices:
        bounding_hull_2D[0].append(func_val[vertex,0])
        bounding_hull_2D[1].append(func_val[vertex,1])

    bounding_hull_2D[0].append(bounding_hull_2D[0][0])
    bounding_hull_2D[1].append(bounding_hull_2D[1][0])    
    return bounding_hull_2D
```

Any suggestions are appreciated